# "RuntimeException: Unable to determine class for field type found in the configuration"

Tags: 8, entities

I got this error while updating from Drupal 8.3.7 to Drupal 8.4.0.

> RuntimeException: Unable to determine class for field type 'webform' found in the 'field.storage.node.webform' configuration in Drupal\field\FieldStorageConfigStorage->mapFromStorageRecords() (line 157 of core/modules/field/src/FieldStorageConfigStorage.php).

How can I fix this error?

Comment: I think this is not connected to the D8 version. Probably all versions will report the same error when you have a field configured in a content type where the code for the field type can't be found.

Comment: Yes it's working fine. when i run the command 
composer require drupal/simplenews   and 
drush cr

Answer (score 52):

One possible way is that your module is missing from the codebase or has been improperly uninstalled and you've still a field which is using that missing module.

Try the following `drush`/SQL commands to remove the broken field:

```
drush sqlq "DELETE FROM cache_config"
drush sqlq "DELETE FROM config WHERE name = 'field.storage.xxx.xxx' OR data LIKE '%field.storage.xxx.xxx%'"
drush sqlq "DELETE FROM config_snapshot  WHERE name = 'field.storage.xxx.xxx' OR data LIKE '%field.storage.xxx.xxx%'"
```

***Warning***: Don't execute above commands on master/live database. Make a backup before doing any database changes.

Where `field.storage.xxx.xxx` is your reported field storage type (e.g. `field.storage.node.webform`).

If above won't help, check for any other references by:

```
drush sql-dump --ordered-dump | grep field.storage.xxx.xxx
```

At the end you need to rebuild your caches:

```
drush cr
```

Comment: Thanks @kenorb for this great answer. +1

Comment: Thanks for this: I spent almost the whole day attempting to find a solution to this issue.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar error with another module (address in my case).
I could fix it by simply re-install the concerned module with drupal console by the following command:

```
drupal module:install address
```

And back to business :)

Comment: +1 yes I found this to work as well.

Comment: I did the re-install with `composer require drupal/address`  - as someone else did here: https://www.drupal.org/project/address/issues/2868049#comment-12044874

Answer (score 2):

When I see that error my trick is to try enabling the offending module again from the command line and then clearing cache. For example:

```
lando drush cr                                                                                                                                                                             

In FieldStorageConfigStorage.php line 174:

  Unable to determine class for field type 'simplenews_issue' found in the 'field.storage.node.simplenews_issue' configuration  


In DiscoveryTrait.php line 53:

  The "simplenews_issue" plugin does not exist. Valid plugin IDs for Drupal\Core\Field\FieldTypePluginManager are: address, address_zone, address_country, comment, datetime, file_uri, file, image, link, list_float, list_string, list_integer, path, text_  
  with_summary, text, text_long, integer, uri, entity_reference, uuid, float, email, timestamp, string, language, created, changed, map, string_long, password, decimal, boolean                                                                               

lando drush en simplenews                                                                                                                                                                 
 [notice] Already enabled: simplenews
lando drush cr                                                                                                                                                                             
 [success] Cache rebuild complete.
```