# Configuration sync with deleted field

Tags: 8, entities, configuration

I have a field field.storage.node.field_create_ic created with type 'calendar_download_type' and it is one of the contributed module (ics_field). Now, in my local environment I deleted the field and likewise uninstalled the module. I exported the latest configuration. Now, when I push everything to server version and try to browse site or run drush commands like **cr and cim**, it fails with error message:  `Uncaught PHP Exception RuntimeException: "Unable to determine class for field type 'calendar_download_type' found in the 'field.storage.node.field_create_ics' configuration" at..."`
I can understand the error and it is obvious because the server database still has that field. 
Can anyone help me to properly use configuration management with such kind of use case? I can use sql command to delete fields in server database and make it work but I just want to follow the standard way to resolve instead of running sql commands.

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/246060/runtimeexception-unable-to-determine-class-for-field-type-found-in-the-configur