# Webform causing Run-time exception error

Tags: 8, webforms

I'm getting a runtime error (see below) on a local copy of my production website that I cloned from the cloud. It is related to Webform. I'm not sure what is causing this issue, it is preventing me from running drush commands or viewing any other pages. Has anyone else had this issue? I'm on drupal 8.5.

The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.RuntimeException: Unable to determine class for field type 'webform' found in the 'field.field.node.webform.webform' configuration in Drupal\Core\Field\FieldConfigStorageBase->mapFromStorageRecords() (line 28 of core\lib\Drupal\Core\Field\FieldConfigStorageBase.php).

Comment: Was/is the webform node installed?

Comment: Yes, webform node is currently installed.

Comment: My best guess is that something was missing from your exported/imported configuration. @see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/246060/runtimeexception-unable-to-determine-class-for-field-type-found-in-the-configur